# "User-friendly" but secure algorithm for anonymising log files

Tags: security, hash, privacy

I have a set of IIS log files that I'd like to publish for a research study.

However, these contain some sensitive information that I would like to anonymise, eg:

```
UserName=XXXX65
```

I'd like to use an algorithm that retains some "user friendly"-ness for visual inspection of the log files, but which is also secure enough it is impossible / impractical to derive the original UserNames.

I can't just **** out all the UserNames, since it is important to be able to correlate requests from the same username across the logs.

Using SHA1 hashing gives me something like

```
UserName=AD5CBF0BA0A8646EBDBA6BE1B5DA4FCB1F385D39
```

which is just about usable,

SHA256 gives:

```
UserName=C9B84EE0DD2EFA53645D5268602E23A9E788903B31BBEB99C03982D9B50AF70C
```

Which is starting to get too long to be usable,

and [PBKDF2-SHA1 hashing](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing) gives

```
UserName=1000:153JkeeGAqtG2UsHX57RBqm3O0DIkXhF:31BBDlQrUqqeyaMo/ikCJAXRC4fFXf82
```

which in my opinion is much too long to be usable.

Is there an algorithm that gives a relatively short one way hash but remains secure / non--reversible?

I'm looking for something where you can scan the log files with your eye, and still notice UserName correlations.

Comment: One way hash doesn't sound like something that will help anonymity. If I make a smart guess that 'root' is a possible user, then I can apply the hash function myself to know which logs correspond to root.

Comment: hashing the user name is reversible.  After all you have a list of all the user names,  that makes it trivial to break because you already have the mapping back to plain text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One way hashes aren't really anonymous.** Why? One can easily verify which user corresponds to which hash:

1. Say `"root"` is a user.
2. You apply `hash("root")` and it turns out the result is `foo`. You publish logs containing several references to `foo`.
3. I make a smart guess that `root` is a user on your machine. I then apply `hash("root")` myself and obtain `foo`. Now I know which logs correspond to `"root"`.

So in essence: Hashes are useful when you later want to be able to verify from the published logs that a certain user was the cause of a certain log. Not when the goal is anonymity.

**Plus, hashes are difficult to read.**

**I'd generate random pronounceable strings, and map one to each user name.** Then publish the logs using the random strings. Truly anonymous and truly readable.

How to produce random pronounceable strings? **Alternate consonants and vowels. Here's how to do it with C** (of course, this only produces a random 6 character string. You need more logic to go with it when processing your logs, like: mapping each user name to a string, making sure strings are unique):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 6

#define RAND_CHAR(string) \
  ( (string)[rand () % strlen (string)])

int main (void)
{
  char vowel[] = "aeiou";
  char consonant[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
  int i;

  char rand_name[NAME_LENGTH + 1];

  srand (time (NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < NAME_LENGTH; i++)
    rand_name[i] = (i % 2) ? RAND_CHAR (vowel) : RAND_CHAR (consonant);

  rand_name[NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';

  printf ("%s\n", rand_name);

  return 0;
}
```

**Here's some examples it produced for me:**

*cemala

gogipa

topeqe

lixate

fasota

rironu*

If the number of users you serve is comparable to *125 * 21<sup>3</sup>*, you need to generate longer strings, and maybe use separators to make it easy to pronounce:

*cemala-gogipa*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this technique.  The only downside I can see is that I would need to find a secure yet accessible place to store the lookup table.  This was why I was hoping to there was a standard algorithmic method of generating "friendly yet secure" hashes.

Comment: @DavidLaing - Why do you want to *store* the lookup? I'd just build the lookup (in memory, as a map) as I go through processing the log file(s), then drop it once I have finished anonymising the log(s). The only reason *storing* the mapping would be useful is when you want to reproduce the original logs from the published anonymized ones. Is that what you want to do? If so, why (especially since you already have the original logs with you)?

Comment: You make a good point - I guess I'm just covering for the eventually that I need to re-anonymise a future set of logs and would like the anonymised usernames to remain consistent with those already published.

Comment: @DavidLaing - That does seem like a reasonable thing to want to do.